# Google Cloud Translation API: Language Detection Algorithm

Tags: google-translate

I'm wondering which algorithms are used in Google Cloud Translation API to detect the language?

And how is the confidence level calculated?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Google does not expose publicly at this point the model it is using for language detection in the Translation API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've already read the documentation and the links. But I'm wondering if the translation service and language detection service use the same model?

Comment: @Liwei you're right, I didn't read your question correctly. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help nonetheless!